# Http 500.19 0x8007000d error on IIS hosting. (windows 7)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7, visual-studio-2019

im programming net core web app. And i try to publish the app on an other machine. Im programming on Visual studio 2019 and i want to use the site in local on a windows 7 machine.
I have of course download the Net core Bundle 5.0.17 to make the web app work. and by the way it work perfectly fine on my personnal windows 11 pc. But when launchin it the the Win7, and going into my site "localhost/test_deploiement" it print :

HTTP 500.19 internal serveur error.
module IIS Web Core
Begin Request
0x8007000d
\?
\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_deploiement\web.config

sources: -1:  0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\test_deploiement.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 2BC12E6D-A122-4BFD-98D7-62CCF65BDF47-->
```

if you have any clues i would be very helpfull. btw i already read old post but is was for windows server 8 and not my windows7 x64.

i did download some dll filed that are missing on my compute. but, my company don't allow me to connect my pc on the internet so im quite limited... and i did instal rewrite module, (but its not used in the app so didn't solve my probleme)

> - Found an invalid ASP.NET Core handler as { Name: aspNetCore, Path: *, State: Enabled, Module: AspNetCoreModule, Entry Type: Local } because ASP.NET Core module version 1 is missing.
>   No valid ASP.NET Core handler is registered for this web site.
>   To run ASP.NET Core on IIS, please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index for more details.

did run the jexus manager but i don't know how to properly fix this probleme of version of core module v1...

Comment: Run a report and the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html There are too many things that can be wrong, and you shouldn't use end of life .NET 5 and Windows 7 either.

Comment: Thanks for you're fast awnser, of the end of life aspect, i am limited by my company and i have no other chose to program on visual studio 2019 and test it on the windows 7.  i edit my question with the error.

Comment: Okay, i Relaunch the web site and it now work. Don't know if it Asp.Core 7.0 or 2.0 module that helped. but it now working. thus the same error message appear in the jexus manager so i hope it will not disfonction an other time. Thank Lex Li !

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed or unidentified XML element. IIS can't identify the XML elements of the modules that are not installed. For example, IIS URL Rewrite module.

Resolution:

Use one of the following methods:

- Delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or
  Web.config file.
- Check the unidentified XML elements, and then install the relevant IIS modules.

More information you can refer to this link: [HRESULT code 0x8007000d](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-500-19-webpage#hresult-code-0x8007000d).

Comment: The `web.config` is posted above. You should post out what's wrong if this is an answer.

Comment: its the microsoft help center but wasnt helpfull.